# Ngninx HTTP Speed vs. HTTPS Speed

Tags: nginx, ssl, http, https

I installed a testsetup to find the impact of ssl on nginx performance (requests per second)

I don't understand a behaviour with the Testsetup I have here.

The setup:

a nearly naked Ubuntu 12.04 with:
- Apache listening on Port 8080 for HTTP Request serving the standard static welcome page.
- Nginx as a reverse proxy with 2 sites:
- default passing http to apache
- default-ssl playing ssl endpoint for the apache server

the "problem" is: i get nearly double the request per second with ssl compared to simple http. How can it be?

this is my default config:

```
server {
   listen *:80;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
}
```

this is the default-ssl config:

```
server {
   listen *:443;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key server.key;
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        add_header Front-End-Https on;
   }
}
```

Can anybody explain to me why this happens, or what I am doing wrong?

I'm using wrk to test:

```
wrk -t8 -c400 -r10m https://serverip/
```

Armin

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere this behaviour might happen when the port 80 on the server is shared and there is a lot of request. As the 443 port is not so used, the speed might be higher.